# How to reuse code in Protractor / AngularJS Testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

We have several Protractor end to end tests for our AngularJS app in several JS files and they work great. But, there is a lot of duplicated code throughout the tests and we would like to DRY that up.

For instance, every time we log in, we have to click on the text elements, type in the username and password, and then click enter. And right now every single JS file has its own copy of the login function which is called before every test.

It would be nice to refactor those out into modules that we can then import. I have been searching for hours, but not found a good solution.

How should we do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create nodejs modules and include them in protractor configuration

**login-helpers.js**

```
exports.loginToPage = function () {
    //nodejs code to login
};
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    //...
    onPrepare: function () {
        protractor.loginHelpers = require('./helpers/login-helpers.js');
    }
    //...
};
```

**page.spec.js**

```
it('should do smth', () => {
    protractor.loginHelpers.loginToPage()

    //expect(...).toBe(...);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure login-helpers shouldn't be `module.exports.loginToPage = function...`

Comment: Can you let us know why you bind the `loginToPage` function onto `exports`?

Answer (score 1):

Our team uses [Orchid-js](https://orchid-js.github.io/introduction/) with Jasmine and Protractor, it's designed to do exactly this.

**Your test**

```
Describe('Login user',require('../login.js'))("username","password");
```

**login.js**

```
module.exports = function(username,password){ 
    describe('login the user',function(){
        it('should login the user',function(){
            element(by.id('usernameField')).sendKeys(username);
            element(by.id('passwordField')).sendKeys(password);
            element(by.id('loginButton')).click();
        });
    });
}
```